# Unix sorting in descending order also finding a string with the given word

Tags: linux, unix

what is wrong with my code?
Nothing is showing up.

- Output the first three elements of a recursive list of file names and attributes in the `lib0` directory containing the string `"go"`, sort the list in descending order of the number of hard links, add the output of access errors to the standard output stream

```
ls -lR 2>&1 | grep "go"  2>&1 | sort -r -n | head -3
```

Comment: Debug your code by adding parts step-by-step, i.e. run `ls -lR` first, then `ls -lR | grep "go"` etc... Using `2>&1` at the current places is wrong. This will mix the error messages with the normal output, then extract all lines from this combination that match the pattern `go`. If you want to combine the filtered output with the error messages, you might have to this using `{` your commands `} 2>&1

Comment: `sort` and `head` are not likely to be suppressing any output, so it would seem that there are no names in the working directory that contain the string `go`.  Perhaps you intended to add a path argument to `ls`.

Comment: ls -lR 2>&1 | ggrep "go"  2>&1 | sort -r -n k-5 | head -3 this works!
Thanks fellas.